# How to do a guid match with ElasticSearch using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have ES documents where a field is a guid.

When I try to do a match, the dashes wreak havoc in my search and I get a bunch of unrelated partial matches.

Since this field is a guid, it always require an exact match.

In Kibana, I can wrap the guid in quotes and I get exact matches; with NEST, quotes don’t help. I have also tried to escape the dashes without any success.

I need to store the guid as is since in some cases I have to retrieve the document with the guid intact, so I can’t remove the dashes in there.

Is there a way to flag that field, with NEST, so that when I query it only exact matches are returned?

---

edit:
following the answer below, here is what I did:

- I added [Nest.Keyword] to the guid field
- I made the query like this:

  ```
  var R = await _ElasticClient.SearchAsync<PictureObject>(Sr => Sr
      .Query(Q => Q.Term(Te => Te
      .Field(F => F.AlbumId)   <- the guid field
      .Value(IdString));  <- my value
  ```

But this doesn't return anything.

The elastic site's documentation gives an example (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-query-usage.html):

```
q
.Terms(c => c
.Name("named_query")
.Boost(1.1)
.Field(p => p.Description)
.Terms("term1", "term2")
)
```

I can't find any documentation about the *Name* method and what I did seems similar, for the single field so I have no idea what impact it has in my case, if any.

The mapping of my field, seen from Kibana, is:

```
 "mapping": {
    "pictureobject": {
      "properties": {
        "AlbumId": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
```

,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Map the `Guid` as a [`keyword` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) and use term level queries such as [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to find exact matches.

```
var r = await _ElasticClient.SearchAsync<PictureObject>(sr => sr
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(te => te
            .Field(f => f.AlbumId.Suffix("keyword"))
            .Value(IdString)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I've edited the question with the test I have done using the keyword type

Comment: @Thomas Use `AlbumIb.keyword` as field.

Comment: what do you mean? that what the (F => F.AlbumId) does, doesn't it?

Comment: @Thomas You've edited the attribute mapping on the POCO, but that will not affect the mapping that already exists in Elasticsearch, which has mapped the field as a `text` datatype with a `keyword` sub-field. Majority of changes to mapping cannot be made to a mapping that already exists, so you would need to create a new index with the desired mapping, then index your documents into it. You do however, already have a `keyword` sub-field to work with as @NishantSaini points out. To target this, you can use `.Field(F => F.AlbumId.Suffix("keyword"))` with the `term` query.

Comment: @Thomas I'd recommend having a read of the mapping documentation as I think it'll help here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/mapping.html

Comment: I have re-indexed ES; with kibana, 'AlbumId: "b58712eb-8704-4ad0-a48a-30b0d072368e"' returns results; however, the code: Q.Term(Te => Te.Field(F => F.AlbumId.Suffix("keyword")).Value("b58712eb-8704-4ad0-a48a-30b0d072368e")); doesn't return anything.

Comment: Have you re-indexed documents into a new index with AlbumId mapped as a `keyword` field? If the index you're re-indexing into has the same mapping as before, you'll get the same result as before. *Note:* your Kibana query uses Pascal casing, but NEST will camel case POCO property names by default, so `AlbumId -> albumId`. You can set `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(s => s)` on `ConnectionSettings` to use property names as is

Comment: that was the problem! thanks a lot Russ (and Nishant); in a way ES makes me think a bit about Mongo, where I realized a few years back that the C# docs only make sense after you understand the primary api and structure. And I think that's the same with ES and that's why you've rescued me several times! thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I am late to the party but You can use MatchPhrase Methode like this sample:

```
await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Employee>(
                s => s.Index(IndexName).Query(
                    q => q.MatchPhrase(tq =>
                        tq.Field(x => x.DepartmentId).Query(dep.Id.ToString())))
```